# Why is this not transitive R = {(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The relation neither reflexive nor irreflexive. It is symmetric. But I do not understand why it is not transitive.

Comment: Draw three dots and label them 1,2,3. Now draw an arrow between any two points in the relation (for example, draw a line from 1 to 3. If the relation is transitive, then if you can get to some node by following the arrows, then there must be a direct arrow (in the same direction) between the two nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $3$ is related to $1$, and $1$ is related to $3$ - but is $3$ related to $3$?

Comment: Why does it have to relate to itself?

Comment: Well, transitivity says, "Whenever A is related to B and B is related to C, then A is related to C." Here we have A=3, B=1, C=3.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now

Comment: But does that mean that transitivity implies reflexivity?

Comment: @PhoxKiD No; for instance, the relation $\{(1, 2)\}$ on $\{1, 2\}$ (always specify the set your relation is on!) is transitive, but not reflexive. If a relation is *symmetric*, and *transitive*, and every element is related to at least one element (this is sometimes called "totality"), then it is reflexive: for each element $a$, let $b$ be such that $(a, b)$ is in the relation, then by symmetry $(b, a)$ is in the relation, so by transitivity $(a, a)$ is in the relation.

Comment: For a more natural example of a transitive but not reflexive relation, consider the relation "$<$" on the real numbers.